# parsed complex json deserialization with gson separating the objects, lists

Tags: java, android, json, gson, json-deserialization

Here is the JSON that I get back from rest

```
{
"tag": "Flight Search Results",
"success": "1",
"xml_filename": "dom_one_20150604172653.xml",
"data": [
    {
        "depart_from_location": "Bangalore",
        "depart_from_location_code": "BLR",
        "depart_to_location": "Calicut",
        "depart_to_location_code": "CCJ",
        "depart_date": "Fri, 05 June 2015",
        "return_from_location": "Calicut",
        "return_from_location_code": "CCJ",
        "return_to_location": "Bangalore",
        "return_to_location_code": "BLR",
        "return_date": "Sat, 06 June 2015",
        "total_onward_flights": 71,
        "departure_details": [
            {
                "flight_id": "arzoo11",
                "flights_count": "2",
                "flight_details": [
                    {
                        "image_filename": "http://live.arzoo.com/FlightWS/image/AirIndia.gif",
                        "airline_name": "Air India",
                        "airline_code": "AI",
                        "flight_number": "608",
                        "departure_location": "Bangalore ",
                        "departure_location_code": "BLR",
                        "departure_date": "2015-06-15",
                        "departure_time": "21:20:00",
                        "arrival_location": "Mumbai",
                        "arrival_location_code": "BOM",
                        "arrival_date": "2015-06-15",
                        "arrival_time": "23:00:00",
                        "travel_time": "1h 40m",
                        "fare_rules": "This fare is Non Refundable Booking Class : T|Cancellation Penalty: All bookings done are subject to cancellation penalty levied by the airlines.<br>In addition to the airlines cancellation penalty, we charge a service fee of Rs. 50 per passenger for all cancellations.|Date Change Penalty: In addition to the airlines date change penalty, we charge a service fee of Rs. 50 per passenger.|"
                    },
                    {
                        "image_filename": "http://live.arzoo.com/FlightWS/image/AirIndia.gif",
                        "airline_name": "Air India",
                        "airline_code": "AI",
                        "flight_number": "657",
                        "departure_location": "Mumbai",
                        "departure_location_code": "BOM",
                        "departure_date": "2015-06-16",
                        "departure_time": "10:00:00",
                        "arrival_location": "Calicut",
                        "arrival_location_code": "CCJ",
                        "arrival_date": "2015-06-16",
                        "arrival_time": "13:05:00",
                        "travel_time": "3h 5m",
                        "fare_rules": "This fare is Non Refundable Booking Class : T|Cancellation Penalty: All bookings done are subject to cancellation penalty levied by the airlines.<br>In addition to the airlines cancellation penalty, we charge a service fee of Rs. 50 per passenger for all cancellations.|Date Change Penalty: In addition to the airlines date change penalty, we charge a service fee of Rs. 50 per passenger.|"
                    }
                ],
                "fare_details": {
                    "base_fare": "7301",
                    "airport_tax": "5365",
                    "service_tax": "46",
                    "transaction_charge": "0",
                    "total": "12962",
                    "total_amount": "12962.00"
                }
            },
            {
                "flight_id": "arzoo12",
                "flights_count": "2",
                "flight_details": [
                    {
                        "image_filename": "http://live.arzoo.com/FlightWS/image/AirIndia.gif",
                        "airline_name": "Air India",
                        "airline_code": "AI",
                        "flight_number": "610",
                        "departure_location": "Bangalore ",
                        "departure_location_code": "BLR",
                        "departure_date": "2015-06-15",
                        "departure_time": "19:00:00",
                        "arrival_location": "Mumbai",
                        "arrival_location_code": "BOM",
                        "arrival_date": "2015-06-15",
                        "arrival_time": "20:55:00",
                        "travel_time": "1h 55m",
                        "fare_rules": "This fare is Non Refundable Booking Class : T|Cancellation Penalty: All bookings done are subject to cancellation penalty levied by the airlines.<br>In addition to the airlines cancellation penalty, we charge a service fee of Rs. 50 per passenger for all cancellations.|Date Change Penalty: In addition to the airlines date change penalty, we charge a service fee of Rs. 50 per passenger.|"
                    },
                    {
                        "image_filename": "http://live.arzoo.com/FlightWS/image/AirIndia.gif",
                        "airline_name": "Air India",
                        "airline_code": "AI",
                        "flight_number": "657",
                        "departure_location": "Mumbai",
                        "departure_location_code": "BOM",
                        "departure_date": "2015-06-16",
                        "departure_time": "10:00:00",
                        "arrival_location": "Calicut",
                        "arrival_location_code": "CCJ",
                        "arrival_date": "2015-06-16",
                        "arrival_time": "13:05:00",
                        "travel_time": "3h 5m",
                        "fare_rules": "This fare is Non Refundable Booking Class : T|Cancellation Penalty: All bookings done are subject to cancellation penalty levied by the airlines.<br>In addition to the airlines cancellation penalty, we charge a service fee of Rs. 50 per passenger for all cancellations.|Date Change Penalty: In addition to the airlines date change penalty, we charge a service fee of Rs. 50 per passenger.|"
                    }
                ],
                "fare_details": {
                    "base_fare": "7301",
                    "airport_tax": "5365",
                    "service_tax": "46",
                    "transaction_charge": "0",
                    "total": "12962",
                    "total_amount": "12962.00"
                }
            },
            {
                "flight_id": "arzoo13",
                "flights_count": "2",
                "flight_details": [
                    {
                        "image_filename": "http://live.arzoo.com/FlightWS/image/AirIndia.gif",
                        "airline_name": "Air India",
                        "airline_code": "AI",
                        "flight_number": "604",
                        "departure_location": "Bangalore ",
                        "departure_location_code": "BLR",
                        "departure_date": "2015-06-15",
                        "departure_time": "08:30:00",
                        "arrival_location": "Mumbai",
                        "arrival_location_code": "BOM",
                        "arrival_date": "2015-06-15",
                        "arrival_time": "10:20:00",
                        "travel_time": "1h 50m",
                        "fare_rules": "This fare is Non Refundable Booking Class : T|Cancellation Penalty: All bookings done are subject to cancellation penalty levied by the airlines.<br>In addition to the airlines cancellation penalty, we charge a service fee of Rs. 50 per passenger for all cancellations.|Date Change Penalty: In addition to the airlines date change penalty, we charge a service fee of Rs. 50 per passenger.|"
                    },
                    {
                        "image_filename": "http://live.arzoo.com/FlightWS/image/AirIndia.gif",
                        "airline_name": "Air India",
                        "airline_code": "AI",
                        "flight_number": "657",
                        "departure_location": "Mumbai",
                        "departure_location_code": "BOM",
                        "departure_date": "2015-06-16",
                        "departure_time": "10:00:00",
                        "arrival_location": "Calicut",
                        "arrival_location_code": "CCJ",
                        "arrival_date": "2015-06-16",
                        "arrival_time": "13:05:00",
                        "travel_time": "3h 5m",
                        "fare_rules": "This fare is Non Refundable Booking Class : T|Cancellation Penalty: All bookings done are subject to cancellation penalty levied by the airlines.<br>In addition to the airlines cancellation penalty, we charge a service fee of Rs. 50 per passenger for all cancellations.|Date Change Penalty: In addition to the airlines date change penalty, we charge a service fee of Rs. 50 per passenger.|"
                    }
                ],
                "fare_details": {
                    "base_fare": "7301",
                    "airport_tax": "5365",
                    "service_tax": "46",
                    "transaction_charge": "0",
                    "total": "12962",
                    "total_amount": "12962.00"
                }
            }
        ],
        "total_return_flights": 0,
        "return_details": []
    }
],
"message": "The flight search results are successfully retrieved"}
```

I have created POJO files using on gson.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Data data = gson.fromJson(JsonString, Data.class);
```

How do I store all flight numbers individually for showing on listview.I guess I need to do something like this;

```
List<FightDetails> flight = data.getFlightDetails();
flight.getFlightNumber();
```

Basically when I debug on "data" I am seeing all nested fields on debugger. However when I try to call nested class,

```
FlightDetails flightdetails = gson.from(jsonString, Flightdetails.class);
```

I am getting back null the flightdetails results.

So I will have bunch of different flightNumber by different flight details json array. 
How do I have these flightNumber and show them off merging with flightId?

***Imagine a flight provider page. A round-trip multistops flight has a flight_id and has 2 separate flight_number below flight_details.***

Comment: Why are you calling GSON *again*? When you called it the first time, didn't it parse *everything* into your `Data` object and embedded objects? Why not just loop like this: `for (FlightDetails flightdetails : data.getData())`?

Comment: I do try it but I am not getting the proper output. 
I use hashmap for keeping every each values  and put these values on a arraylist to show all on listview. 
Basically
HashMap<String, Object> hashMap;
List<HashMap<String, Object>> holdAllValuesonList;

for (FlightDetails flightdetails : data.getData()){
hashMap.put("flightNumbers", flightdetails.getFlightNumber());
holdAllValuesonList.add(hashMap)}

Comment: I am getting back the last flightNumber from Json to holdAllValuesonList. Not all flightNumbers in Json.